# What is blankInfoSec property used for in dbpedia and others

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

The question is in the title.
The property http://dbpedia.org/property/blankInfoSec can be found in some documents. 
for example http://dbpedia.org/page/Barcelona.

What is the meaning of this property in dbpedia gibberish ? 
How is it used ? What is the semantic meaning of it (geez I'm starting to speak like a real semantic web geek) .

:)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, that property has no semantic meaning. Instead of using `languages_type` and `languages` pair, the article's infobox uses custom a key-value pair (`blank_name_sec1` and `blank_info_sec1`). Such names come from infobox templates. You can find that the Country template has a language key-value pair, but the Settlement template hasn't.

You can reference the original article's markup (`{{Infobox settlement}}` section) and [Template:Infobox settlement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox_settlement).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm accessing dbPedia from java ( using Jena). How am I supposed to know the title of that property ? Is there a way to automatically "expand" that property to figure out its "real" name / display name?

Comment: As far is I know all such properties have word `blank` in their name. Assuming that you can filter it. For example `regex(str(?predicate), "_?blank[0-9]*_")`.